# Configuring Bolt CMS for pretty URLs on IIS

Tags: bolt-cms

I have installed the Bolt CMS using IIS on Windows Server 2008 R2, and the site home page and all of the admin pages work fine, but any other pages that have been  created within the admin are displaying a fatal error with the following message:  •Class: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException •Message: The page could not be found, and there is no 'notfound' set in 'config.yml'. Sorry about that.

I have the rewrite module installed in IIS and tried importing the .htaccess file so that the PHP handler will process extensionless URL's, but that did not resolve this problem.

Any assistance with resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Todd

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem recently. Here are the settings I am using. First, go to your site in IIS Manager, open "URL Rewrite" and add a new rule.

**Match URL**

- Requested URL: Matches the Pattern
- Using: Regular Expressions
- Pattern: I used `^cms/` since I have it in a subfolder. You may want just `^/`

**Conditions**

- Logical grouping: Match All
- Add condition "Is Not a File" and "Is Not a Directory"

**Action**

- Action type: Rewrite
- Rewrite URL: `cms/index.php` (again you may want to remove the cms and just have `index.php`)
- Tick "Append query string"
- Tick "Stop processing of subsequent rules"